# Type of class-field based on generic

Tags: typescript, generics, union-types

Imagine the following code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQwJYBsECMUQCrggZygF4oBvAKCiqgHIEAnehEGgLlkeYB4EA7EAHwBuStRr5g9JLwDmbKBKmyR1WgHt0AKwgBjYPI3a9IgL7lyOtPkIB1JmEj0u2KBAAewCLwAmhANYQIGoAZrCIqBhYuJD4AmTmqgD0iVAAkoQQSMAAFhD0UAxMIAA0CpLSMlBq+Ya6wKJUYFKInlD0EAjearwoIFCgkOzYIg1QyVAAogBKUwDyU+wACvRqjqC0iCgArhA0UNkIhLxqUNJZSAgoSABeeQU+p0dqwFDeEMFnnr0F1kgyvBBvKdeP1clAdN1FFs9NUAHSjJpIFrQdqdbrfTY7djwZBoTA4PD4ADa2AAuiNVBDeFCYfQABQDCBDACU8VUqhySHwsMZxH6eAp7KoiQAVCLRuyRZMZvNWBLVFKoNgAMoAJgAzKrVUM8LQAXA8kTSXsuVBji9Dvg-rxItBgCdeTQcRF8dECCTjbCoAAC73y6iKt16iAG+hGk1PC2-f62-oO3U0fV5GjwoUBxL+hQAdyyOmyUAZeFZFDT7J0h2gdE4LDlpdLnO5mOgJCNKjrQvQqL8bfb5fwlcUFTYmfr2S5sKbfJoNB77eonY63ZH1D7ldqemHc-ZDYnlx2fNIJlnW4XCCXpbMqjMJiAA)):

```js
type AvailableTypes = {
    'array': Array<any>;
    'string': string;
    'object': object;
}

class Wrapper<T extends keyof AvailableTypes> {

    // Is either array, string or object
    private readonly type: T;

    // ERROR: Property 'value' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
    private readonly value: AvailableTypes[T];

    constructor(type: T) {
        this.type = type;

        /**
         * ERROR:
         *  TS2322: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'AvailableTypes[T]'.   
         *  Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
         */
        switch (type) {
            case 'array':
                this.value = [];
                break;
            case 'string':
                this.value = '';
                break;
            case 'object':
                this.value = {};
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

There are two major errors:

> TS2322: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'AvailableTypes[T]'.
>   Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'never'

Even if `AvailableTypes[T]` always resolves to a one of the types declared in `AvailableTypes`, with `T` being the key of it.

... and

> Property 'value' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Although `type` is mandatory and need to be either `string`, `array` or `object.`

What am I missing here?

Possible related SO Threads:

- [Typescript Generic Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325728/typescript-generic-union)
- [Create union out of interface using tag generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813343/create-union-out-of-interface-using-tag-generic)
- [TypeScript: use of generic and union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355643/typescript-use-of-generic-and-union-types)

#### Update

(update to [@jcalz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913036/7664765))
It should be possible to type-check the `value` based on the `type` property:

```js
// In the Wrapper class, should work since value can only be an array if type is 'array':
public pushValue(val: unknown) {
    if (this.type === 'array') {
        this.value.push(val);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQwJYBsECMUQCrggZygF4oBvAKCiqgHIEAnehEGgLlkeYB4EA7EAHwBuStRr5g9JLwDmbKBKmyR1WgHt0AKwgBjYPI3a9IgL7lyOtPkIB1JmEj0u2KBAAewCLwAmhANYQIGoAZrCIqBhYuJD4AmTmqgD0iVAAkoQQSMAAFhD0UAxMIAA0CpLSMlBq+Ya6wKJUYFKInlD0EAjearwoIFCgkOzYIg1QyVAAogBKUwDyU+wACvRqjqC0iCgArhA0UNkIhLxqUNJZSAgoSABeeQU+p0dqwFDeEMFnnr0F1kgyvBBvKdeP1clAdN1FFs9NUAHSjJpIFrQdqdbrfTY7djwZBoTA4PD4ADa2AAuiNVBDeFCYfQABQDCBDACU8VUqhySHwsMZxH6eAp7KoiQAVCLRuyRZMZvNWBLVFKoNgAMoAJgAzKrVUM8LQAXA8kTSXsuVBji9Dvg-rxItBgCdeTQcRF8dECCTjbCoAAC73y6iKt16iAG+hGk1PC2-f62-oO3U0fV5GjwoUBxL+hQAdyyOmyUAZeFZFDT7J0h2gdE4LDlpdLnO5mOgJCNKjrQvQqL8bfb5fwlcUFTYmfr2S5sKbfJoNB77eonY63ZH1D7ldqemHc-ZDYnlx2fNIJlnW4XCCXpbMqjMCK2mCQOigYC2+GyADU9xA6Zt2FteH5jlmvDFpmSChAyY7cryRDQbQhTMDQwFbjuTawk+L5fpczLHtQl44eQJhAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying issue is that generic type parameters are not narrowed via control flow analysis, which is a fairly longstanding open issue in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for more information.

When you check `type` in a `switch`/`case` statement, the compiler can narrow the type of the `type` variable to the literal type `"array"`, but it does not narrow the *type parameter* `T` to `"array"`. And therefore it cannot verify that it's safe to assign an `any[]` value to the type `AvailableTypes[T]`.  The compiler would have to perform some analysis it currently does not do, such as "okay, if `type === "array"`, and we inferred `T` from the type of `type`, then inside this `case` block we can narrow `T` to `"array"`, and therefore the type of `this.value` is `AvailableTypes["array"]`, a.k.a., `any[]`, and so it is safe to assign `[]` to it."  But this doesn't happen.

The same problem is causing the "`value` isn't definitely assigned" error.  The compiler doesn't have the wherewithal to see that the `switch`/`case` exhausts all the possibilities for `T` since it doesn't do control flow analysis here.

---

The easiest workaround here is to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing since it can't verify it.

To handle the exhaustiveness issue, you can either make a `default` case that throws, as in:

```
class Wrapper<T extends keyof AvailableTypes> {

    private readonly type: T;
    private readonly value: AvailableTypes[T];
    constructor(type: T) {
        this.type = type;

        switch (type) {
            case 'array':
                this.value = [] as AvailableTypes[T]; // assert
                break;
            case 'string':
                this.value = '' as AvailableTypes[T]; // assert
                break;
            case 'object':
                this.value = {} as AvailableTypes[T]; // assert
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error("HOW DID THIS HAPPEN"); // exhaustive
        }
    }
}
```

or you can widen `type` from `T` to `keyof AvailableTypes`, which will let the compiler perform the control flow analysis necessary for it to understand that the cases are exhaustive:

```
class Wrapper<T extends keyof AvailableTypes> {
    private readonly type: T;
    private readonly value: AvailableTypes[T];
    constructor(type: T) {
        this.type = type;
        const _type: keyof AvailableTypes = type; // widen to concrete type
        switch (_type) {
            case 'array':
                this.value = [] as AvailableTypes[T]; // assert
                break;
            case 'string':
                this.value = '' as AvailableTypes[T]; // assert
                break;
            case 'object':
                this.value = {} as AvailableTypes[T]; // assert
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another workaround ([mentioned in a comment by person who implemented the soundness change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559)) is to take advantage of the fact that if you have a value `t` of type `T`, and a key `k` of type `K extends keyof T`, then the type of `t[k]` will be seen by the compiler as `T[K]`.  So if we can make a valid `AvailableTypes`, we can just index into it with `type`.  Maybe like this:

```
class Wrapper<T extends keyof AvailableTypes> {
    private readonly type: T
    private readonly value: AvailableTypes[T];
    constructor(type: T) {
        this.type = type;
        const initValues: AvailableTypes = {
            array: [],
            string: "",
            object: {}
        };
        this.value = initValues[type];
    }
}
```

This is by far a nicer way to go than type assertions and `switch` statements, and is fairly type safe to boot.  So I'd go with this solution unless your use case prohibits it.

---

Okay, hope one of those helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?ssl=9&ssc=5&pln=31&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQwJYBsECMUQCrggZygF4oBvAKCiqgHIEAnehEGgLlkeYB4EA7EAHwBuStRr5g9JLwDmbKBKmyR1WgHt0AKwgBjYPI3a9IgL5Ry5XggC2BMAh3QY+fBHrAYvACYBhNbx16CGBoClEqHTQXKAB1JjBIei5sKAgADxDvQgBrCBA1ADNYRFQMLFxIfAEycNUoMClEEKgghC9-FBAoUEh2bBU6qgakJuhW9t5OqEQUAFcIdnhkNEwcPHwAbWwAXQHBnX9FWb01egAKHoWobABKGsHB4AALJHwAOkvibrw9h4jD4BQAD6l3YuXyRSWpVWFQIX0uvz++AA7khgDonlAziC8HcKH8-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-1NkuKq-g8qAvKAA)

---

update: [discriminated union instead of generic classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARAlleAnNY2gBcIATAVWDQHtgkBvAKHqWaXgBsQookBBLLEAE8A6gJgwIWOkxaysEEMWptBSAoIlIAvEgBEIfkN0zZzeYuWqAbiDYBXCAC4kIYIIDaAXW1IvJ0zB2UAAWAGq2DgAUNmzOdsAA1sCUAO7AAJTSptlqwRgAdDEO+YEh0bbpANz+sgC+-vWy7JzcAMoEOMAA5qIg4pJZOeZKwCpqGsg6ulAd+F3GOUjDlkhFTkgznV0+ugssjSzNXEgA8gBGAFYQ8AS9-VIMi8ujquqaU5SX1wR72c9ja2cnyuNx8tAOzAhrGoMyQKTEEiw3B0jxyXQgBBchkEkUytCWGLsWBowAgKV42LuiKQtQANDUWOjMcDvri6ASCESSWTTl8blSBnSGcwmRtZt02fj5JziUhSeT2lsBVIoVC3shlcjxhJKAAzOEIyRQaqydVIZU+TXuBIQQR682GpGear+eAwzGcADCBEoUh0AB4eEgIAAPIjAYjcVweTy0pAAJQAfJFdcBnJF8pmDF0oM4eJktImEwWi6mXFG3OW5TyM1msDm8yWEybDu6HX1qTovT6sJF-QAVYNhiAR7g2u36zXJ9XOfvpZxW-veQvCg0do3udWefxVRiyXXxG5UGhBCDKyIpBeOvGrtD6i-5M1aZ96AwCQS6G+LWQpEpBMIRBAkS6AAXpQlAwJ+q6qvQ9T0EAA)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! But when I'm trying to check if `type` is `array`, and try to push something into the value it fails :( Even if `type` is _basically_ strictly bound to the _value_ property...

Comment: I don’t see that in the question; did I miss it? Or is this a separate or follow-up question?  A [mcve] always helps also.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, I've update the question - the `type` property was actually meant to be used for that purpose!

Comment: The issue is the same, and the only solution I see without complete refactoring is a type assertion:  `(this.value as AvailableTypes["array"]).push(val);`.  Had I known you were planning to do such manipulation inside the implementation of `Wrapper` I'd suggest that you use a discriminated union instead, and either not use classes or use a family of subclasses (one subclass for each member of the union).

Comment: I added a playground link to the bottom of my answer showing how a discriminated union with sibling classes might work better than a single generic class. good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot for the great explanation and the issue link. I faced similar issues few times but couldn't found any helpful information. *Discriminated union* solution is very clever